# No matching provisioning profiles [for transferred apps ]

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.ios, visual-studio-2017, provisioning-profile

I have transferred few apps from one apple account to another. All the App IDs has been transferred successfully to new account. Then I created new provisioning profiles under new account. Then downloaded them on Mac manually but when i'm trying to assign profile in VS 2017 then Visual studio can't find the profile (refer the attached screenshot below)

[image]

I can easily find and assign the profiles for the apps which has not been transferred.

Note - I tried making a sample project in XCode. Xcode is able to find and attach the provisioning profile for transferred apps.

Comment: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/357083#Comment_357083 refer to this similar issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Meanwhile you can build try Resigning the apps and upload them.

Download the mobile provision and Signing certificate manually in the keychain and
Use the following Commands:

```
unzip app.ipa

rm -rf Payload/MyApp.app/_CodeSignature/

/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy Payload/MyApp.app/Info.plist

Set :CFBundleIdentifier com.mycompany.newbundleidentifier
save
quit

cp ~/Downloads/AdHoc.mobileprovision Payload/MyApp.app/embedded.mobileprovision 

codesign -f -s "iPhone Distribution: Company Certificate" --entitlements entitlements.plist  Payload/MyApp.app

zip -qr app-resigned.ipa Payload/
```